# URL Aliases - Patterns Error

Tags: path-aliases, tokens

I'm getting a list of the following errors in my new drupal website. Any idea where this is coming from and what I need to do to fix it?

```
The Default path pattern (applies to all content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Applications (applies to all Applications content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Careers (applies to all Careers content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Events (applies to all Events content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Executive Team (applies to all Executive Team content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for News (applies to all News content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:created:custom:Y], [node:created:custom:m], [node:created:custom:d], [node:title].
The Pattern for all Products paths is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for SlideShow (applies to all SlideShow content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Solutions (applies to all Solutions content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Test Type (applies to all Test Type content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern for Webform (applies to all Webform content types with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title].
The Default path pattern (applies to all vocabularies with blank patterns below) is using the following invalid tokens: [term:vocabulary], [term:name].
The Pattern for user account page paths is using the following invalid tokens: [user:name].
```

Comment: It's either the pattern is not existing or token module is not enabled. check the pattern if existing and if token module is enabled.

Comment: So the modules are installed - but I don't understand how to set the patterns correctly.. I copies the db from the current live site that works..  what do I do about the invalid token error?

Comment: have you tried running cron and flushing all caches?

Comment: I did flush the cache multiple times.  I don't know what is meant by running cron.

Comment: if you haven't run it you can go to admin/config/system/cron and click run cron. and you can check your url alias here if it's same as in live site /admin/config/search/path/patterns

Comment: After I ran cron manually from Status Report, there is an error '
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.' when I try to go to almost any admin screen.

Comment: can you check the db log or php error logs?

Comment: There aren't any recent errors..

Comment: can you compare the pattern in your local to live site (check if its the same)? just want to know if all are the same. maybe we could get some clue from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44212/discussion-between-mg1-and-iamroald).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case other might encounter it and bump in this page. To recap on how we fixed this error. In @MG1 case, restore the database from live site and downgrading the php version on her local machine from 7.0.8 to 5.4.42 and upgrading the Drupal core module in latest version did fixed the problem all errors are gone.

We also encounter this one just in case other's encountered it.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   form_process_autocomplete() in
>   /Users/***/Documents/Sites/Link-New/includes/form.inc on line
>   1850

this one help us out in trouble https://www.drupal.org/node/2610498

Note:
This might be fix in other way but in MG1 case this solved the problem.